# DJI SDK "Home point not recorded yet." error Code: -5010

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, dji-sdk

Hey ya'll so Im trying to start a DJIWaypointMission and am getting an error when I call "startMissionExecutionWithCompletion" I've apparently successfully uploaded the mission to the drone using prepareMission.

The error its giving me is "Home point not recorded yet." I looked at the documentation for a method of setting a home point and haven't found anything and I have scanned through the listed methods of the DJIMissionManager object as well as the DJIWayPointObject to no avail. I also tried adding the "aircraftLocation" taken from the current state of the drone.

Below is the code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import DJISDK
import Foundation

class FlyToPointsViewController: DJIBaseViewController, DJIFlightControllerDelegate, DJIMissionManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var mission: DJIWaypointMission? = nil
    var flightController: DJIFlightController?=nil
    var missionCoordinates=[CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    var allSteps = [DJIWaypoint]()
    var missionManager: DJIMissionManager?=nil
    var currentState: DJIFlightControllerCurrentState?=nil

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello Team", message:
            "There are quite a few easter eggs hidden away in here. Hopefully you find them and have a good laugh. Sorry I couldn't make it to test, the mountains are calling. But I put alot of time into this so hopefully it works as expected. I didn't add a return to home functionality to make this a bit spicy for ya so make sure your last point is near you other wise you're gonna do a bit of walking... Cheers ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //initialize our aircraft
        mapView.delegate=self

        let aircraft: DJIAircraft? = self.fetchAircraft()
        if aircraft != nil {
            //makes the view controller watch for particular functions like the flight controller one below
            aircraft!.delegate = self
            aircraft!.flightController?.delegate = self
        }
        else{
            print("aircraft not found")
        }

        self.missionManager=DJIMissionManager.sharedInstance()
        self.missionManager?.delegate=self

        //initialize core location to put mapp on our location
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }


        //start uploading location into manager object so we can use .location method
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        //let location = manager.location!.coordinate; //get ipads current location and turn it into a coordinated

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.0150, -105.2705)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 7000, 7000) //create a square region using center point and size of square
        mapView.region = region //tells the mapview to center itself around this region

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        let aircraft: DJIAircraft? = self.fetchAircraft()
        if aircraft != nil {
            if aircraft!.flightController?.delegate === self {
                aircraft!.flightController!.delegate = nil
            }
        }

    }



    @IBAction func revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began { return }
        let touchLocation = sender.locationInView(mapView)
        let locationCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchLocation, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
        self.missionCoordinates.append(locationCoordinate)

        print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")
        let annotation = CustomMissionPressLocation(location: locationCoordinate)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    //Mark: - Functions Called from Button Presses
    @IBAction func clearCoordinates(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.missionCoordinates=[]
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    }


    @IBAction func startMission(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (!self.missionCoordinates.isEmpty){
            print("start Mission Attempted")
            self.mission = DJIWaypointMission()
            self.mission!.autoFlightSpeed=10
            self.mission!.maxFlightSpeed=15
            self.mission!.exitMissionOnRCSignalLost=true
            let waypoint = DJIWaypoint(coordinate: (self.currentState?.aircraftLocation)!)

            waypoint.altitude=15
            waypoint.speed=10
            waypoint.heading=0
            waypoint.actionRepeatTimes = 1
            waypoint.actionTimeoutInSeconds = 60
            waypoint.cornerRadiusInMeters = 5
            waypoint.turnMode = DJIWaypointTurnMode.Clockwise
            self.mission!.addWaypoint(waypoint)

            for locations in self.missionCoordinates{
                let waypoint = DJIWaypoint(coordinate: locations)
                waypoint.altitude=15
                waypoint.speed=10
                waypoint.heading=0
                waypoint.actionRepeatTimes = 1
                waypoint.actionTimeoutInSeconds = 60
                waypoint.cornerRadiusInMeters = 5
                waypoint.turnMode = DJIWaypointTurnMode.Clockwise

                self.mission!.addWaypoint(waypoint)
            }
            let waypointStep = DJIWaypointStep(waypointMission: self.mission!)


        self.startWayPointMission()
        }

        else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Mission Error", message:
                "you haven't added any waypoints ya dingus", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    //avoids a bunch of knuckleheads from sending the drone to china
    func missionIsntTooFar()-> Bool{
        let startLoc=self.currentState?.aircraftLocation
        let locations = self.missionCoordinates
        //let startLoc=locations[0]

        for locs in locations{
            let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPointForCoordinate(startLoc!), MKMapPointForCoordinate(locs))
            if distance > 4000{
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    func startWayPointMission() {
        if self.missionIsntTooFar(){
            self.missionManager?.prepareMission(self.mission!, withProgress: nil, withCompletion: {[weak self]
                (error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    print("uploaded")

                    print(String(self?.missionManager?.isMissionReadyToExecute))
                    self?.missionManager?.startMissionExecutionWithCompletion({[weak self]
                        (error: NSError?)->Void in

                        if error == nil{
                            print("mission started")
                        }
                        else{
                            print("error: \(error!)")
                        }
                        })
                }
                else {
                    self?.showAlertResult("mission upload failed \(error!)")
                }
                })
        }

        else{
            mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Mission is too far", message:
                "you're trying to fly the drone too far ya knucklehead", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    //Mark: - Flight Controller Delegate Methods

    func flightController(fc: DJIFlightController, didUpdateSystemState state: DJIFlightControllerCurrentState) {
        self.flightController=fc
        self.currentState=state
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
extension FlyToPointsViewController: MKMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let annotationView = DroneAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Attraction")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false //we're going to customize the callout
        return annotationView
    }

}
```

I've been stuck for several hours and was hoping someone had seen this before. As always if and when I solve the problem I will post the solution here and on DJI's forum.

I'm calling it for the night though.

Cheers

Comment: Hmmm pretty cool dji has an API.

Comment: Yea. It's actually pretty powerful. If you want to get really into it you can buy the matrice for a whopping 3,000 and you can code the onboard computer and the guidance system.

Or you can go with the 3DR solo which you can code in python and comes with a programmable onboard computer with easily accessible inputs and outputs

Comment: @LukeWorley did you manage to solve that? After uploading the mission the aircraft loses the home point and because of that, don't return home after finishes the mission

Answer (score 0):

So two things appear to have been wrong

A)

```
    self.flightController?.setHomeLocationUsingAircraftCurrentLocationWithCompletion(nil)


self.mission!.finishedAction=DJIWaypointMissionFinishedAction.GoHome
```

B)

also the drone has to have taken off before you can upload the mission therefore call

```
        self.flightController?.takeoffWithCompletion({[weak self]
```

before trying to upload the mission.

P.S. For some reason you need to give it atleast two waypoints for it to be a valid mission.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to manually establish the aircraft's home point.  But, you do need to wait until the drone has obtained a sufficient GPS fix in order for it to set itself.

If you implement the DJIFlightControllerDelegate didUpdate:state method, you can check state.homeLocation to see if it has been set yet.

Also, you can upload a mission to the drone before takeoff, just don't spin up the rotors.  It will do that for you when you start the mission.